# Loading a template from a CMS page

Tags: pwa

I'm working on a Magento 2.4 PWA system. The idea is to load a template from a CMS page.

I'm using `{{block class="Company\Module\Block\Index\Index" template="Company_Module::index/index.phtml"}}` in the CMS page, but it doesn't load or render anything in the page. I know it does something because if the reference to the template is wrong, the system returns an error.

That's all I'm doing. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: is it work with Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template?

{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  template="Company_Module::index/index.phtml"}}

Comment: Thanks, S.P. Sadly, it does not.